# HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error Number Format Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, numberformatexception

Here is the servlet file, when i run it, numberformatexception is thrown, client is the class here.
*output error when we put data in the fields*, Don't know what to do. As I have tried all methods but it is still not working. As we post code here. you can review it.*

```
    Type Exception Report
    Message null
    Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
    Exception
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        emlakcontroller.ClientServlet.doPost(ClientServlet.java:53)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

*ClientServlet.java*

```
    /**
    * Servlet implementation class ClientServlet
   */ 
    @WebServlet("/register")
    public class ClientServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ClientDAO clientDao=new ClientDAO();
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public ClientServlet() 
        {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {   
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String email=request.getParameter("email");  
            String password=request.getParameter("password");  
            int contact=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact"));  
            Client client=new Client();
            client.setName(name);
            client.setEmail(email);
            client.setPassword(password);
            client.setContact(contact); 
            try 
            {
                clientDao.registerClient(client);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
              {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              out.print("Yahoo! register successful");  
              RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("SignupFront.html");  
              rd.include(request,response); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you're sending `null` where a number is expected. You didn't give us any information about how you're calling your endpoint, so I can only guess that you don't send a `contact` parameter in your request. Btw, what is `contact` and why is it an `int`?

Comment: The exception is very much clear. Integer parsing is throwing error. Checkout the value you are passing for the parameter contact. Try to debug

Comment: Please provide the payload of your POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the `request.getParameter("contact");` returns null and you try to parse it to integer. Try this:

```
String contactStr = request.getParameter("contact");
if (contactStr != null) {
    int contact = Integer.parseInt();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned stacktrace should have been enough to troubleshoot this.

As you can see in there the following can be noted:

```
Exception
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

This effectively tells you that a conversion to a number has failed due to a value being `null`. From the code that you provided the only place where this is possible is the following:

```
int contact=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact"));
```

Therefore you should do the following:

1. Make sure that `request.getParameter("contact")` returns a **non-null** value.
2. Make sure that `request.getParameter("contact")` returns a value that can be parsed into an `Integer`, otherwise the process will fail with the same error.